# When using Express with NodeJS - How Does View Cache Work?

Tags: node.js, caching, view, express

**Express API:**

> view cache: Enables view template compilation caching, enabled in production by default

**I have 2 questions:**

1. In app.js `view cache` isn't explicitly set in the development block, should it be?
2. How does this caching mechanism work; is it analagous to memcache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see it from the [source](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/531f024e486c13eb6d7e2bc0966ea95b1567197a/lib/application.js#L114), view cache is enabled by default only on `production` environment. If you don't need caching on `development` (or other environments) you can omit setting it explicitly.

How view caching works instead is pretty simple. If enabled, express stores compiled template in process memory and renders the cached version. This way no temporary cache files are generated and the template is retrieved quickly from memory.

Comment: this cache is not working when you have the same express with different urls requesting differente data, it will always return the same template with the same content for everyone :(.